# Can I SELECT the AVG of 'x' values from two tables but only select the values where the 'y' values match? (INNER JOIN)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the average of two values which are in two different tables. I only want to get the average of the values where the in the same column the 'Week' Values of both tables are the same.

So e.g.:

```
Table1 Name= BicepsTable

    Week | Biceps
    
    1 | 33
    
    2 | 33.2
    
    3 | 34.1
    
    .

Table2 Name=ThighTable

Week | Thigh

1 | 42.1

3 | 42.8

4 | 43

.
```

From these tables I want to have the values {(1, 37.55), (3, 38.45)}.

( . (33+42)/2=37.55 . . . . (34.1+42.8)/2=38.45 . )

I tried to get this with the following code but the following code gives me {(1, 37.55), (3, 37.55)} where the second value is wrong, the second average value should be the one of the next column.

```
   sql = 'SELECT BicepsTable.Week, 
          ((SELECT BicepsTable.Biceps FROM BicepsTable INNER JOIN ThighTable ON BicepsTable.Week = ThighTable.Week)
          +
          (SELECT ThighTable.Thigh FROM ThighTable INNER JOIN BicepsTable ON ThighTable.Week = BicepsTable.Week)) /2
          FROM BicepsTable INNER JOIN ThighTable ON BicepsTable.Week = ThighTable.Week'
```

Please help, if you don't understand my problem, or got questions, feel free to ask:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest taking a union of the two tables, and then taking the average of each week:

```
SELECT Week, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM 
(
    SELECT Week, Biceps AS rating FROM BicepsTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Week, Thigh FROM ThighTable
) t
GROUP BY Week
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY Week;
```

Aggregation, as used above, is a good option here, because the `AVG` will only operate on the values which are present.  So, if only one or the other table has a value, then the average will reflect that.

Comment: Woops, I'm sorry but this answer is not right, it selects all weeks not only the weeks that are the same

Comment: @JoshuavanDalsum Then add a `HAVING` clause to the outer query which retains only weeks which appear twice, implying that both the biceps and thigh tables had that given week.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @test1 as table
(id int,t1value float)
declare @test2 as table
(id int,t2value float)

insert into @test1
values(1,100),(2,150),(3,200)

insert into @test2
values(1,100),(3,150),(5,200)

select *,(a.t1value+b.t2value)/2 taverage from @test1 a
inner join @test2 b on a.[id]=b.[id]
group by a.id,a.t1value,b.id,b.t2value
```